# how to use IronPython to debug the Script step by step?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, ironpython

I'm working on a project in which I am creating a IronPython compiler depend on IronPython ,
But I have some problem on debugging the Script and can use breakpoint ? could you please give me some help ? thanks. all my code is there: [https://github.com/heyxEvget/IronPython-Debugger]

```
  public ScriptEngine GetEngine()
    {
        if (_engine != null)
            return _engine;
        _engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        _engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(_stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        _engine.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(_stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string ironPythonLibPath = string.Format(@"{0}\IronPythonLib.zip", path);
        var paths = _engine.GetSearchPaths() as List<string> ?? new List<string>();
        paths.Add(path);
        paths.Add(ironPythonLibPath);
        path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IRONPYTHONPATH");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            var pathStrings = path.Split(';');
            paths.AddRange(pathStrings.Where(p => p.Length > 0));
        }
        _engine.SetSearchPaths(paths.ToArray());
        return _engine;
    }

    private void GetPythonVarsInfo(ScriptScope scope)
    {
        _varList.Clear();
        var items = scope.GetItems();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            _varList.Add(new VarValue
            {
                VarName = item.Key,
                Value = item.Value
            });
        }
        valueListView.ItemsSource = _varList;
    }

    private void OnExecuteButtonClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string outPutString = string.Empty;
        outPutString = "*************************************" +
            "Excute Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        ExeceutePython(document, outPutString);
        TabControl.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }

    private void ExeceutePython(EditorDocument document, string outPutString)
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = GetEngine();
        string script = document.Text;
        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script);
        ScriptScope scope = _engine.CreateScope();
        try
        {
            source.Compile();
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(outPutString + Environment.NewLine);
            var result = source.Execute(scope);
            if (result != null)
            {
                OutputTextBox.AppendText(engine.Operations.Format(result));
            }
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            GetPythonVarsInfo(scope);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var eo = engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>();
            var eoString = eo.FormatException(ex);
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(eoString);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should provide much more information on your problem, including some code and what you have tried. However as far as I know you cannot debug a script within c#. mAybe the following link will also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369279/is-there-any-way-to-debug-python-code-embedded-in-c-sharp-with-visual-studio-and

Comment: hi,I am just starting learn IronPython with its help document, and I want to create a Python compiler whit C# Code depend on Ironpython engine and I havn't find that the Python Engine has any method to debug the script. so I ask someone for help there.

Comment: I use syntaxeditor as my editting control  which Create by Actiprosoftware.so I just need complate the code behind which is used for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Given this setup code to create the IronPython script engine

```
var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Debug", ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True }});
Debug.Assert(engine.Runtime.Setup.DebugMode);

var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("script.py");
dynamic result = source.Execute();
```

You can then use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
```

inside your scripts to get the debugger to break.

[image: example script]
[image: example script debugging]

Comment: hi, I am sorry that maybe I have not explain my problem clearly. I want Crate a  Python Script Debugger just using some Dlls Which provided by IronPython. I use the Control (Named SyntaxEditor) which provided by Actiprosoftware as my foreground,and use IronPython DLLS to Debuge the code which I have Inserted breakpoint. thanks all the same

Comment: `ScriptEngine engine = GetEngine();
    string script = document.Text;
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script);
    ScriptScope scope = _engine.CreateScope();
    source.Compile();
    OutputTextBox.AppendText(outPutString + Environment.NewLine);
    var result = source.Execute(scope);`

Comment: you can see my main code there:[link](https://github.com/heyxEvget/IronPython-Debugger)

Comment: this excellent older example still works, and the screenshots explain how to use the call stack window. this setup also mostly works with the watch window. However, I've been wondering - is there a way to make Visual Studio's IronPython Interactive window work with variables in the script.py (i.e. make it connect to same debugging session)?
e.g. If I startup Python Interactive window from scratch, I can get import clr and get VS completions on clr. (e.g. AddReference, etc). But neither when writing script.py nor when inspecting variables in script.py in watch window - do I get completions.

Comment: yes, I am. and to clarify, I am looking for completions not only on built-in libraries such as clr, but also on any custom objects/classes, etc, which is why I am trying to "connect" the Python Interactive window that PTVS provides to the debugging session of the engine that I have in memory as created in your example above.

Comment: I posted this as a separate question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449916/can-vss-ironpython-interactive-window-work-with-variables-in-py-file-invoked-f

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual studio isolated shell for that
[Visual Studio Isolated Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry, I mean that I want create a Python Script Compiler depend on IronPython by using C# code.